# Why does my selection callback get called on my second Listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
listbox = None
listboxMultiple = None
listboxStr = None
listboxMultipleStr = None

def main():
    global root
    global listboxStr
    global listboxMultipleStr
    global listbox
    global listboxMultiple

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exitApplication)
    root.title("Title Name")
    root.option_add('*tearOff', False)  # don't allow tear-off menus
    root.geometry('1600x300')

    listboxStr = StringVar()
    listboxStr.set("ABCD")
    listbox = Listbox(root, name="lb1", listvariable=listboxStr, width=120)
    listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
    listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", selectListItemCallback)

    listboxMultipleStr = StringVar()
    listboxMultipleStr.set("")
    listboxMultiple = Listbox(root, name="lb2", listvariable=listboxMultipleStr, width=120)
    listboxMultiple.pack(side=LEFT)
    root.mainloop()


def selectListItemCallback(event):
    global listboxMultipleStr
    global listbox
    global listboxMultiple

    print("event.widget is {} and listbox is {} and listboxMultiple is {}\n".format(event.widget, listbox, listboxMultiple))
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    listboxMultipleStr.set("")
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        newvalue = "{}\n{}".format(data,"SOMETHING")
        print("selected \"{}\"\n".format( data ))
        print("newvalue is \"{}\"\n".format( newvalue ))
        listboxMultiple.insert(END, "{}".format(data))
        listboxMultiple.insert(END, "SOMETHING")
        #listboxMultipleStr.set( newvalue )
    else:
        pass

def exitApplication():
    global root
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Using python3 on Windows 7. I've setup a callback "selectListItemCallback" for one of my two listbox widgets. And yet, when I click on the text in "lb1" it works as expected, I update "lb2" with the same selected text plus I add another line to "lb2".

The issue is, when I then select the item in "lb2", it still calls the callback and the event.widget is "lb1" and not "lb2".

My intent is to have a list of items in 'lb1' and when I select any of them, then 'lb2' gets filled with info related to the selected 'lb1' item.  And, I don't want a selection callback invoked in my 'lb2' widget.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong that could be causing this strange behavior?

Thank you.

I've posted the code; and this does run on my Windows 7 machine using python3.  Python 3.8.6 to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the event fires when the first list box loses the selection when you click on the other list box. The event fires whenever the selection *changes*, not just when it is set.

If you don't want the first listbox to lose its selection when you click in the second listbox, set `exportselection` to `False` for the listboxes. Otherwise, tkinter will only allow one to have a selection at a time.